# How can I determine which items in a GridView that are visible in the current scroll window?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a GridView in my main app page and I want to do some background processing for the items that are currently in view for the user (high priority), and then of course do the other items too (low priority).

I can access the ScrollBar and the ScrollViewer, but none of them appear to tell me which of my items are in the current scroll window. I could try to hack this in, but it gets tricky because the number of row/columns change based on the size of the scroll region.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br209745.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.aspx

Any help much appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two general ways you can do this. The first is to get the `GridViewItem`'s `AutomationPeer`, which actually has a direct method to call. [Class information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.automation.peers.gridviewitemautomationpeer). I've had problems getting this to actually be usable though. Luckily, there's a second answer. It will require some math to be done, but it's doable.

1. Get the item container, in this case a `GridViewItem`, using the `GridView`'s `ItemContainerGenerator`.
2. Get the `GridView`'s `ScrollViewer`. You can search for `FindVisualChild<T>` methods, there are plenty around.
3. Do `MyGridViewItem.TransformToVisual(MyGridViewScrollViewer).TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));` This will get you the top left corner of the item, relative to the *entire scrollable panel* (known as its `Extent`) of the `ScrollViewer` (this will be important later).

This will return to you a `Point` object.

Next, we'll need to find out the range of `X` values that are currently being displayed in the `ScrollViewer`.

*Note: If you're using a Vertical scrolling `ScrollViewer`, use the `Height`s. Horizontal, use the `Width`s. Both, use both. I am going to do my example using the Horizontal/Width.*

1. Take the `HorizontalOffset`. This is your current 'lower bound' for the current viewable region.
2. Take the `HorizontalOffset` plus the `ViewportWidth`. This is the upper bound of the current viewable region.
3. If your `Point.X` is greater than your *lower bound* and less than your *upper bound*, then the item is visible.

If you further need to find out if the *whole* item is visible, do
    this same calculation for `Point.X + GridViewItem.Width`.

Hope this helps, and happy coding!

Comment: one correction #3 is incorrect. it will give you the item's position relative to the screen's viewport, so I only need to make sure the item's origin is not negative and not beyong the ViewPortWidth/Height.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow step #1. If you don't know what items are in view -- how do you start with the GridViewItem? I guess more specifically, what property/method in GridView.ItemContainerGenerator gives you this item?

Comment: In this case, he will have to iterate over his list and do this each time. This has the benefit that, in the case of multiple columns/rows, he will be able to always find them, but is obviously difficult to use for large lists.

There are some things that he can do to improve the efficiency for large lists, such as take note when he gets to the section of items that are 'in view' and when he leaves that section of the list (then stop iterating at that point).

Comment: @NateDiamond Is there a code snippet to follow? I am so sorry I am not able to understand the flow

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VisualTreeHelper` to scan the visual tree as Nate suggests, but this is usually not recommended at runtime, especially for tight loops (e.g. checking lots of `GridViewItem` objects) or complex visual trees. You could do a minor improvement and only calculate the position of these items once and then do a simplified check based on the `ScrollViewer.ViewChanged` event and offset values, but that still seems a bit too complicated.

If your `GridView` uses an `ItemsPanel` that supports virtualization (e.g. the default `WrapGrid`) - most of the items that are actually loaded into `GridView` items are actually visible or not far off the screen, so if you bind your `GridView` to a collection of view models using `ItemsSource` - you can figure out when these items are accessed by binding to their properties or handling `Loaded`/`Unloaded` events on the `ItemTemplate` and call back to the view models to know when they are getting accessed. That way you can start loading these items when they first start showing up on screen and leave the logic to determine whether they should be loaded to the list control virtualization implementation in the platform.

Comment: Won't Loaded be also fired for the ones outside of the scroll view area? If so this won't work for me. I need to distinguish the two so i can adjust their priorities for background loading dynamically whenever the user scrolls.

Comment: It will do it for ones that are a little bit off the screen, but not for all of them. That's how virtualization works - it creates container UI elements for the items that need to show up on screen and a few more that can be quickly rendered if the user scrolls off the currently visible area, so this is what would most likely be what you need.