# fetch gridViewItem from a GridView from codeBehind UWP

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp

I am working on a UWP application trying to implement the `Transform3DAnimations` as from the platform samples using a `GridView` instead of a `HubSection`. I've got it all figured out except for fetching the `GridViewItem`. The below code is from the sample in context to a hubsection.

```
private void UpdateRandomSection()
    {
        // Updating the section triggers a cool animation!
        // See SectionView.xaml and SectionView.xaml.cs

        var sectionsInView = HeadlinesHub.SectionsInView;
        var sectionsCount = sectionsInView.Count;

        if (sectionsCount > 0)
        {
            var sectionToUpdate = sectionsInView[_random.Next(sectionsCount)];
            sectionToUpdate.DataContext = new HeroArticlesViewModel();
        }
    }
```

I am trying to fetch the `GridViewItem`, but I am unable to fetch the `GridViewItem` it always returns me the data model of the `GridViewItem`. How can I get the `GridViewItem` from the `GridView`? My code is below:

```
private Random InAppLiveTileRandomTileNumberGenerator;
private void UpdateRandomSection()
    {
        var sectionsInView = AllDevicesGridView.Items;
        var sectionsCount = sectionsInView.Count;

        if (sectionsCount > 0)
        {
            var sectionToUpdate = (GridViewItem)AllDevicesGridView.Items[InAppLiveTileRandomTileNumberGenerator.Next(sectionsCount)]; //Invalid Cast exception here
            sectionToUpdate.DataContext = new InappLiveTileViewModelModel();
        }
    }
```

---

[Link to the sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlTransform3DAnimations/cs)

[Solution I tried from stack answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705800/how-can-i-determine-which-items-in-a-gridview-that-are-visible-in-the-current-sc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your code line  `var sectionToUpdate = (GridViewItem)AllDevicesGridView.Items[InAppLiveTileRandomTileNumberGenerator.Next(sectionsCount)];` it will returns the data model of the `GridViewItem` as you seen. To get the [`GridViewItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GridViewItem) you may need to use [`ContainerFromItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ContainerFromItem_System_Object_) method. For example, if you want to get the `GridViewItem` object from the selected item code may as follows:

```
 private void listViewDirectory_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {        
     var container = AllDevicesGridView.ContainerFromItem(AllDevicesGridView.SelectedItem);
     GridViewItem item = container as GridViewItem;
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.ActualHeight);
 }
```

It seems like you want get a special item with item index assigned:

```
var container = AllDevicesGridView.ContainerFromItem(AllDevicesGridView.Items[1]);
GridViewItem item = container as GridViewItem;
```

If you want to get data context of the `GridViewItem`, you may need to get the [`ListViewItemPresenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.listviewitempresenter) from `GridViewItem`. Here I use the [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.VisualTreeHelper#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_VisualTreeHelper_FindElementsInHostCoordinates_Windows_Foundation_Point_Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_) to get the `ListViewItemPresenter`. By the way, `VisualTreeHelper` is not recommended to use unless you don't have other ways.

```
private void listViewDirectory_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var container = AllDevicesGridView.ContainerFromItem(AllDevicesGridView.Items[1]);
    GridViewItem item = container as GridViewItem;
    ListViewItemPresenter itempresenter;
    IEnumerable<ListViewItemPresenter> items = FindVisualChildren<ListViewItemPresenter>(item);
    int count = items.Count();
    itempresenter = items.ElementAt<ListViewItemPresenter>(0);           
    itempresenter.DataContext = new Person() { Name = "update", Contact = "update" };
}
private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the sample, they use the method to get the items in the current view of the hubsection and then get the container for a random object which is in current view and then change the data context. I don't want to get the container of the object on which there is a selected event or which has been selected. On a timer tick, I want to fetch the items in the current view of the gridview and then fetch a random from them and fetch its container (of type gridviewitem) and then update it's data context. Could you please help. Sorry for my formatting I am using the mobile app

Comment: I tried your code, The `var container = AllDevicesGridView.ContainerFromItem(AllDevicesGridView.Items[1]);` does return me a container but the data context of that container is null. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AdityaSharma, if you need to get or change the item's data context you may need to get the `ListViewItemPresenter` object from the `GridViewItem`. I will update the code to get the data context.

Comment: Just a quick question, you're using a `ListViewItemPresenter` will the GridViewItem's OnViewModelPropertyChanged event would be raised if the `ListViewItemPresenter`'s datacontext is changed?

Comment: @AdityaSharma I'm not sure what is your `OnViewModelPropertyChanged` , but according to your code,  `sectionToUpdate.DataContext = new InappLiveTileViewModelModel();` I think you mean the property changed event handle in the view model. If that  since you create a new  view model instance not update the exist one, in my opinion it will not trigger the event.  You didn't update the binding source just a property of the current item, only current item can be changed. You can use the above code , and set a break point on the event to see if it can be triggered.

Comment: Oh it just worked. Thank you so much. The property was fired. As you said it's completely true but my pluming of the system makes it fire the OnViewModelPropertyChnaged event. again thank you for all the support and the answer. I'll upvote it too